# How to display images aligned to left?

Tags: html, css

I have this:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html; charset=utf8'>
    <style type='text/css'>
        body {
            background-color: #000;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>  
    <img src="1.jpg" height="100%" style="float: left;" />
    <img src="2.jpg" height="100%" style="float: left;" />
    <img src="3.jpg" height="100%" style="float: left;" />
    <img src="4.jpg" height="100%" style="float: left;" />
</body>
</html>
```

This is big images. But my browser show me two images side by side and next in a new line. 
I want to disply it all in one line. How to do it?

Comment: It is a little unclear as to what you want. Do you want the images all in the same row, or do you want the images stacked vertically, but aligned to the left of the container?

Comment: This shows images on android displays. I want to display image filled the entire screen and next on the left.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Stop floating the images and set `white-space: nowrap` on the body or some other wrapper element.

```
body {
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

and:

```
<body>  
    <img src="1.jpg" height="100%" />
    <img src="2.jpg" height="100%" />
    <img src="3.jpg" height="100%" />
    <img src="4.jpg" height="100%" />
</body>
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/4Udam/

Answer (score 1):

Just set really big value to body width:

```
body {
    width:5000px;
}
```

But this will introduce horizontal scrolling, you should know, that people hate to scroll horizontally. Why do you not use some kind of lightbox effect?

Answer (score 0):

Apply `clear: left` to your images as well.

`<img src="1.jpg" height="100%" style="float: left;" />`